# Selectors in an ordered list animated with CSS3 transitions

Tags: css, list, css-selectors, transition

I put together the following ordered list that makes use of transitions. Basically at the bottom of the first three li-elements there is being animated a border-bottom from a slight to a dark grey. Now what I want is to modify this color and make it appear in three different colors. I tried this with spans and li classes already, but had no success. Can anyone of you clarify how I could possibly trigger this behavior according to the given code?

```
 <div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li class="1"><a href="#sectionportfolio">No hacemos uso de cualquier de los componentes prefabricados o mezclas preparadas.</a></li>
    <li class="2"><a href="#sectionportfolio">Una alta calidad en la compra de los ingredientes y la preparación es nuestra principal prioridad.</a></li>
    <li class="3"><a href="#sectionportfolio">Todos nuestros productos se hacen con amor y se han inspirado en recetas familiares.</a></li>
    <li class="4"><a href="#sectionportfolio">Queremos que nuestros clientes estén satisfechos. Si alguna vez tiene motivo de queja, le pedimos que nos devuelva su compra tan pronto como sea posible en nuestra tienda.</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

#list {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#list ul li {
  font: 200 14px/1.5 'oswaldlight';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding:30px 0;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom 1.0s ease, border-bottom 1.4s ease, padding-top 1.0s ease, padding-bottom 1.0s ease, font-size 0.7s ease, background-color 0.3s ease, color 1.0s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-bottom  1.0s ease, border-bottom 1.4s ease, padding-top 1.0s ease, padding-bottom 1.0s ease, font-size 0.7s ease, background-color 0.3s ease, color 1.0s ease;
  -o-transition: border-bottom 1.0s ease, border-bottom 1.4s ease, padding-top 1.0s ease, padding-bottom 1.0s ease, font-size 0.7s ease, background-color 0.3s ease, color 1.0s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-bottom 1.0s ease, border-bottom 1.4s ease, padding-top 1.0s ease, padding-bottom 1.0s ease, font-size 0.7s ease, background-color 0.3s ease, color 1.0s ease;
  transition: border-bottom 1.0s ease, border-bottom 1.4s ease, padding-top 1.0s ease, padding-bottom 1.0s ease, font-size 0.7s ease, background-color 0.3s ease, color 1.0s ease;
  border-spacing:0;
  cursor:crosshair;

}

#list ul li:hover {

  border-bottom: 4px solid #858585;
  padding:40px 0px 5px 0x;
  border-spacing:0;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #454545;
  cursor:pointer;
}


#list ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

#list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888;
  text-align:center;
}


#list li a:hover {
    cursor:pointer;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used `:nth-child()`, is it what you want?

```
#list ul li:hover {
  padding:40px 0px 5px 0x;
  border-spacing:0;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #454545;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#list ul li:nth-child(1):hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;    
}

#list ul li:nth-child(2):hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;    
}

#list ul li:nth-child(3):hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid green;    
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/edisonator/EZ52x/)

Comment: You, Sir, are fabulous. I bow before you. I did not come across this. It is sheerly beautiful. And pure css just how i love it! Thanks for your efforts!